# Reverse engineering a Java package diagram in Visual Paradigm

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering, visual-paradigm, package-diagram

I am using Visual Paradigm to create UML diagrams from an existing Java project.

I am following the steps described in [How to reversee engineer UML from Java in Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/277/28011_reverseengin.html).

I am trying to create a package diagram from existing packages, but Visual Paradigm isn't able to show me relationships between packages, so every package is drawn as separated from the others, whereas I need to know relationships too.

Any tips to make Visual Paradigm show me them?

Comment: I don't know VP but package dependencies aren' created in any tool I know. You will likely have to do that by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Instant Reverse feature (the link you showing) do support reverse Java source to Package Diagram. You can specify the target at the bottom of the dialog.
[image]

Comment: Already did, but this won't show the dependencies (in form of relationships between packages) that I need.

Comment: Just tested again by reverse java.security package using Instant Reverse and it generate package diagram with dependency and containment info as https://files2.visual-paradigm.com/index.php/s/UJejn7lnnY4e9VI